# Showing errors with error_reporting(E_ALL)

Tags: php, error-reporting

I am using error_reporting(E_ALL) to show errors and it works fine. Currently I put this function on every page and code for which I wish to show error, this means I am using it hundred times on my project. Is there any way by which I does not have to repeat this function again and again yet it works for whole site, like putting in header or database connection. Sorry if I am asking something stupid but just wanted to be sure if something like might work and is common practice.

Comment: It's common in php to have an include file that contains something needed for the entire site for things like this

Comment: more common to use php.ini or .htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to go about this:

## php.ini

If you have access to it, you should configure this within your [**`php.ini`**](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php) file. This way, the setting will be applied globally and you won't need to include that function in every file.

```
display_errors = On
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

## .htaccess

Some hosting providers allow you to create an `.htaccess` file, which lives at the root of your project. The following could also enable errors globally, also allowing you to avoid code repetition

```
php_flag display_errors on
php_flag error_reporting 32767
```

http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php

## file includes

If all else fails, you can continue how you are or take look at how your application/site is being executed. If you have the following code at the beginning-most entry point of your application, any includes will inherit from it. This shines best if all requests route to the same file.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

include 'otherstuff.php'; // will also display errors
```

However if your application has multiple entry points, consider using a common include so you're at least not repeating code.

***includes.php***

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

***index.php***

```
include 'includes.php';

// other code
```

Comment: thanks php.ini seems best practice , i have got `; display_errors
;  Default Value: On
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: Off`  so here I have to remove semicolon before default value and insert `error_reporting()` beneath it ?

Comment: @bɪˈɡɪnə Yup, you'll want to remove the `;` as that determines whether the line is a comment. However, you'll want to ensure `Default Value` is not present in the actual value. Overall, the lines should look exactly how I've added them in the answer above :)